# JavaScript: When assigning an anonymous function to a variable, function return value is not passed, rather the function as a string

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I am trying to learn JavaScript but I've come across a hurdle. If the answer is obvious and reachable through a simple search I apologize in advance. I am a novice to programming and JavaScript, and unsure what line of inquiry to follow.

In the following code, the function takes values from a HTML form, does some processing and sends them back. I've tested the input and output process and it's working correctly.

```
function foo() {

var x = parseInt(document.formdata.fieldone.value);
var y = parseFloat(document.formdata.fieldtwo.value);

if (isNaN(y))
    { var z = x; }
else
    { var z = function(x, y) {
            if ((y * (x / 100)) < 1) {
                return (x + Math.ceil(y * (x / 100))); }
            else if ((y * (x / 100)) > 1) {
                return (x + Math.round(y * (x / 100))); }
            else {
                return 0; } } }

var bar = document.getElementById("output");

bar.innerHTML = z; }
```

The problem is, when the else branch of the conditional statement tries to process the anonymous function, the return value isn't assigned; rather the entirety of the function as a string. That is, the following appears in the HTML page:

> function (x, y) { if ((y * (x / 100)) < 1) { return (x + Math.ceil(y * (x / 100))); } else if ((y * (x / 100)) > 1) { return (x + Math.round(y * (x / 100))); } else { return 0; } }

I've tested the code in Chrome and Firefox and the result is the same.

Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to call the function by passing it two arguments, because otherwise the `z` variable will just store a reference to this function but it will not evaluate it:

```
var z = (function(x, y) {
    if ((y * (x / 100)) < 1) {
        return (x + Math.ceil(y * (x / 100))); }
    else if ((y * (x / 100)) > 1) {
        return (x + Math.round(y * (x / 100))); }
    else {
        return 0; 
    } 
})(x, y);
```

Note that `(x, y)` used inside the anonymous function are not the same as the one passed as arguments at the end which correspond to the two variables declared in the beginning of the `foo` function.

Comment: Thank you, calling the function always helps :)