# Referencing variable,it executes the function,however adding strings to the variable,returns function as string instead of value

Tags: javascript, string, function

The program is supposed to be a live search using php and javascript... where as you type it searches below. I just recently started learning javascript so sorry if my knowledge is limited...

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#results').append('<p>Started</p>');
    var getText = (function () {
        return document.getElementById('year').value;
    });
    var text = getText;
    var getText1 = (function () {
        return document.getElementById('class').value;
    });
    var text1 = getText1;
    setInterval(function () {
        var newText = getText;
        var newText1 = getText1;
        var loading = "search.php?year=" + newText + "&class=" + newText1;
        $('#results').append(newText1);
        if (text !== newText || text1 !== newText1) {
            $('#results').load(loading);
            $('#results').append('somethinghappened');
        };
        text = newText;
        text1 = newText1;
    }, 100);
});
```

so it works fine when i append newText1, however if i try to append "loading" it returns:

> search.php?year=function () { return document.getElementById("year").value; }&class=function () { return document.getElementById("class").value; }

Can anyone explain what the difference between the two cases is and why a difference occurs? and possibly how to fix it so that it loads the correct URL

i searched and found: [JavaScript: When assigning an anonymous function to a variable, function return value is not passed, rather the function as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301851/javascript-when-assigning-an-anonymous-function-to-a-variable-function-return) however didn't quite understand completely what it meant by passing two arguments, and when i tried to do something similar, it didn't work as expected...

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a title, not a story... **:)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var newText = getText;
var newText1 = getText1;
```

You are assigning the functions `getText` and `getText1` to the variables instead of executing them and assigning their return values. Try this instead:

```
var newText = getText();
var newText1 = getText1();
```

Or just:

```
var newText = document.getElementById('year').value;
var newText1 = document.getElementById('class').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

try simply with

```
var getText = document.getElementById('year').value;
var getText1 = document.getElementById('class').value;
```

otherwise you will have only a reference to the function

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling the functions, you're just referencing them.

To call them you need parens, like `getText()`. But why make them functions in this case? They're short and don't take parameters. If you want functions, make a single function that takes the string ID.